# How do I set a pixel color in a texture using ManagedDX?

Tags: c#, directx, gdi, textures

Hey guys, I need to set a specific pixel in a texture to a custom color,
for doing that I made a Bitmap and I always set the pixel in the bitmap,
then I recreate the texture from the bitmap.
Doing that is very time consuming, is there any way to modify the pixel directly
in the texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah you should be able to do it by using the [Texture.LockRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130436(VS.100).aspx) function.  You then need to seek to the correct pixel which will be addressable by jumping to ((y * pitch) + (x * bytesPerPixel)) in the stream.  The you write your new pixel and call [Texture.UnlockRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.direct3d.texture.unlockrectangle(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: And how do I found the bytes per pixel and the pitch?

Comment: The pitch is returned by the LockRectangle call and the number of bytes per pixel is defined by the texture format. A8R8G8B8 is 4 bytes and A1R5G5B5 is 2 bytes, for example.  Add up the bits and divide by 8 to get teh number of bytes.  ie A8R8G8B8 = 8 + 8 + 8 + 8 = 32 bits / 8 = 4 bytes.  Of course if the texture is compressed you are going to have a lot of problems.  Its not a simple process modifying a compressed texel and, tbh, a texture that you need to update in this way ought not to be compressed.